# How to carry out Bergman-Hommel procedure in Python?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python

I read a research paper and saw the authors used Bergman–Hommel procedure to compare multiple algorithms on multiple datasets by analysing an n×n comparison considering the hypothesis of equality between all pairs of algorithms.

I would like to do the same test on my datasets. I was trying to find any available code online but was unable to find it.

Therefore, how do I perform this test using Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with R,  you may utilise scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare and following R code to come up with something in python:

https://gist.github.com/jacksonpradolima/b40aa19325787898fc5ddc3155752d94